# Separating by column with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm running into a real issue here that I can't solve.

I'm taking 7 .txt files, dropping the first row from each (I want to add my own headers) and combining them into one .txt file. I've been successful up until this part. The part I'm having trouble with is changing it to a csv/xlsx that is separated into columns when viewed in Excel. Right now it just puts everything into one row.

Here is my code so far.

```
path = r'C:\Users\rock\Desktop\workspace\DTH'          
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.TXT")

li = []

for filename in all_files:

    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    open(filename, 'w').writelines(lines[1:])
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=False, header=None)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True,) 

frame.to_csv("Test.csv", index=False)  
frame.to_excel("test2.xlsx")
```

I've attached an example image of the[image: csv] that I get with my output.

Data copied from .txt below:

```
WEST                 26/10/2020 13:00:00         13:06:16       01:00:00       FRUIT            HELLO         GOODBYE                                           Done       Sub                    13:00:00          13:06:16         00:06:16                                                                                                  
WEST                 26/10/2020 19:00:00         19:00:42       00:30:00       VEGGIES             CARROT         POTATO                                         Done       Sub                    19:00:00          19:00:42         00:00:42
```

Thanks in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It seems that pandas is not parsing your files as DataFrames. We don't know the contents of your `.txt` files, but it seems that they have values separates by the tab `\t` character. Try adding the named argument `sep='\t'` to your `pd.read_csv` function. If it doesn't work, maybe you could provide us with a sample of your data as a text, not as an image.

Comment: I've tried the ```sep='\t'``` and it didn't work. This may be a dumb question but how do I attach a copy of the .txt files I'm working with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by doing the following:

```
column_headers = [list of header names]
               
df = pd.read_table(filename,sep=r"[ ]{2,}", header=None, skiprows=1, engine='python', names=column_headers)
```

Thanks to those who submitted some possible solutions to try

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
path = r'C:\Users\rock\Desktop\workspace\DTH'          
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.TXT")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    lines = open(filename).readlines()
    open(filename, 'w').writelines(lines[1:])
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter = ',', header=None)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True) 

frame.to_csv("Test.csv", index=None)  
frame.to_excel("test2.xlsx")
```

CSV Table must have character delimiter to be able to separate each rows.

Comment: I still get the same results when trying the above.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel data has not been split into columns (i.e., all data are in Column A); perhaps a fixed-width file got imported into Excel.  Here is one approach, using the text data in the original post:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''
WEST                 26/10/2020 13:00:00         13:06:16       01:00:00       FRUIT            HELLO         GOODBYE                                           Done       Sub                    13:00:00          13:06:16         00:06:16                                                                                                  
WEST                 26/10/2020 19:00:00         19:00:42       00:30:00       VEGGIES             CARROT         POTATO                                         Done       Sub                    19:00:00          19:00:42         00:00:42                                                                                                  
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python', header=None)
print(df.transpose())

                      0                    1
0                  WEST                 WEST
1   26/10/2020 13:00:00  26/10/2020 19:00:00
2              13:06:16             19:00:42
3              01:00:00             00:30:00
4                 FRUIT              VEGGIES
5                 HELLO               CARROT
6               GOODBYE               POTATO
7                  Done                 Done
8                   Sub                  Sub
9              13:00:00             19:00:00
10             13:06:16             19:00:42
11             00:06:16             00:00:42
```

Comment: It does look like its a fixed width from the txt file however that'ts not quite the result I'm looking. I'm tried to get it still within its 12 columns

Comment: I got twelve columns -- my results are just transposed, so it fits without wrapping.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on a dataframe, I tried:
`frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True) `
`cf = pd.read_csv(StringIO(frame), sep='\s\s+', engine='python', header=None)`

and got the error
 `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not DataFrame`

Comment: Actually you just need to add the `sep=\s\s+, engine='python'` to your `pd.read_csv`